# how to set page load timeout for new tab

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.set_page_load_timeout(4)
try:
    browser.get("https://9gag.com")
except:
    print("Page took too much time to load")
```

When I run the above code it will execute except: block always and prints "Page took too much time to load"

But when I run the code below in which I create a page where there is a button with id newPage and it opened the link(9gag) in new tab as soon as it is clicked.
I don't get any exception.It take complete time to load and then print the url of the website

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("file:///F:/documents/html_level_one/link_to_extreme_page_load.html")
browser.set_page_load_timeout(4)
browser.find_element_by_id("newPage").click()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
print(browser.current_url)
```

I am using Firefox 28 and selenium 2.41

[image: my very simple starting page]

Answer (score 1):

Page load timeouts don't apply to clicked elements because Selenium can't know if a new page is being loaded. That's why the page load timeout isn't applied. You could create a WebDriverWait and wait for an element on the page to be visible, etc. and set a timeout that way.

Comment: What if I have to work with multiple elements on same page

Comment: Just add a wait for each element you are looking for. You can also use `WebDriverWait` and use the `expected_conditions` that locate more than one element, e.g. `visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator)`. See [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html).

Comment: :) should I have to use webdriverwait before click() or before switching to new tab or before print() ?

Comment: Before the click

Comment: adding it before the click makes it wait for amount of delay specified and finally it caught an exception and then proceeds :(

Comment: That's exactly what you said you wanted to do. A way to have the page timeout after 4 seconds. You can't do that with a click and `set_page_load_timeout()` so you have to click and then use `WebDriverWait` for 4 seconds.

Comment: Actually I wanted the page in new tab  to stop load.But applying webdriverwait caused it to search in that tab where the button is present(i.e. the webpage created by me).Do I edit my question to show you what I have done?